# button image mouseover popup image in another location (html box)

Tags: javascript, html, popup, mouseover

button image mouseover popup image in another location (html box)

I have a button(image) that i need linked at mouseover to be a popup image in a specific location. How do I change the location of where the popup appears in another html elemnt box? Here is what I have so far, but it was for a link with embedded css in html in order to move it around....so don't know if this will help. I decided to go with buttons because it looks way better. Here is my website that I'm trying to edit to where you hover over the specific button images on the left you will get a popup image pertaining to the button on the right side of the screen http://ultimatefinishdetailing.com/Services.html

HTML:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
 .pop-up {
  height : 50px;
  width : 50px;
  top : 10px;
  left : 0px;
  right : 800px;
  float : right;
}

</style>

<a href="" onmouseover="ShowImage('enter filename')" onmouseout="HideImage()">Ultimate Finish Auto Detailing</a>

<div class="pop-up">

   <img id="popupImage" src="" alt="Popup image" style="display: none"/> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowImage(src)
    {
        var img = document.getElementById('popupImage');
        img.src = src;
        img.style.display = "block";
    }
    function HideImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('popupImage').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

you can see on my site when you hover over the link Ultimate Finish Detailing that the image box (cause i didn't designate one) shows up in the right side of the screen...that's what the above code does. but I need the buttons to do this and all in a certain window

Comment: You're referencing a file on your local computer; this won't work on your website

Comment: i know...nevermind that part....it was a mistake

Comment: i still need help....anyone?